# Asp MVC SMPT mail Dynamic link not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

When i try to send mail, in the code below when i comment the body the mail is working, but the link is showing in blue color in visual studio editor, doesnt through any error, it just not working

this is ScreenShot
[image]

Comment: What is not working? What did you expect to happen? Is it only the highlighting that confuses you?

Comment: Yes and No, Thanks for the support , I figured out, the single quotes was making the trouble i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out thanks for the support

[image]